# find httpd running or not using /etc/init.d/httpd inside script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need use /etc/init.d/httpd status command to verify whether its running or not inside shell.
I don't want to use pidof pgrep etc.  --something like

```
retval=`/etc/init.d/httpd status`
if [ $retval -eq "running" ];then echo "yes" ; else echo "no";fi
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$?` will give you the value of the most recent return code. E.g.

```
/etc/init.d/httpd status > /dev/null # ignore stdout
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "yes"
else 
    echo "no"
fi
```

For more details, see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

Answer (score 0):

You can run your command directly in the `if` statement:

```
if /etc/init.d/httpd status > /dev/null
then
```

Or you can check the output string:

```
retval=$(/etc/init.d/httpd status)
if [[ $retval == *running* ]]
then
```

By the way, `-eq` is a numeric test.